# Fetching multiple raw md files from GitHub in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, github-api

I'm trying to fetch data from multiple raw .md files from Guthub repo. Currently I'm able to fetch only one, yet I need to get to all of them.

I have a github repo and Im looking to fetch data from raw .md file, which is not a problem. The problem is that the repo has bunch of folders and each folder has its own .md file. I need to make some sort of map through all folders and fetch all of the .md files.

Lets say I have a github repo with following folders:

```
folder1 -> text1.md
folder2 -> text2.md
folder3 -> text3.md
```

I'm currently being able to fetch only one raw md usinng the following method

```
let fetchData = () => {    
axios.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user-name/repo-name/master/folder1/text1.md").then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

My goal is to fetch all text1, text2, text3.md so I can map through them and display in the table

Comment: .md is just text file. so then(response => response.data)

Comment: @Robert thank you for your response, but that's not what I'm looking for. My main goal is to get all files in all folders. I think I've managed it by using GitHub trees

Comment: do you know all the folders/files paths in advance or do you want to "browse" through them?

Comment: @Coluccini I browse and check the ones I need, the problem with trees is that I don't get the content from inside, but only folder name, which is not enough for me, I need to give them titles.

Comment: You browse it manually or you need the code to do it for you?

Comment: @Coluccini all in all, I'm setting up a table that maps through all the folders. User will be able to click on each object in the table and see its raw .md file. I'm setting up a function to do so. My problem is that trees method doesn't give me content of what's inside anymore, just the name of the file.

Comment: Ideally if I can get back objects with file names and its data that would be perfect

Comment: Let me know if I'm understanding correctly:
- you have a list of folders
- you can get the file name inside that folder
- you are having problems to fetch the content of those files

Comment: @Coluccini Correct. By using method in the example of this question with axios get request, Im able to get content of specific md. However, with the method that I've mentioned in the replies with tree, Im being able to get list of folders but not content inside of it.

Comment: Why don't you use that function to get the content inside the same function you use to get the file name? Something link `getFolderContent(folder) { filename = getFileName(); content = axios.get(filename); return { filename, content }; }`

Comment: Why don't you use that function to get the content inside the same function you use to get the file name? Something link `getFolderContent(folder) { filename = getFileName(); content = axios.get(filename); return { filename, content }; }`

Comment: @Coluccini that could work, however my task was completely changed, I now have to download all these raw documents on website launch only once since we are using Gatsby.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would say that your best bet is to make a node worker that you can run weekly (o during deployments) that would crawl information form folders (filename and content) you tell pass it to, and then saved that information in some way you can later consume from gatsby (I guess the ideal way would be to put it on gatsby GraphQL).

This is a vague idea on how that worker could be, with the too limited information I have:

```js
let repoBaseUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user-name/repo-name/master/';
let folders = [
  'folder1',
  'folder2',
  'folder3'
];


let fetchFileName = async (folder) => {    
  // Your function to get the filename
  return filename;
}

let fetchFileContent = async (folder, filename) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${repoBaseUrl}${folder}${filename}`);
    return response.data;
  }
  catch(error) {
    // do something with the error
  }
}

let fetchFolderContent = async () => {
  const data = {};
  folders.forEach(async (folder) => {
    const filename = await fetchFileName(folder);
    const content = await fetchFileContent(folder, filename);
    data[folder] = {
      filename,
      content,
    } 
  });
  return data;
}

let main = async () => {
  const data = await fetchFolderContent();
  // Process your data
  // IE: save it GraphQL so you can consume it from Gatsbt
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank you it works, do you know by chance how can I locally save those files that I fetched? For example into a folder called "documents" that I've added into my project.

Comment: You should import `fs` at the beginning (`const fs = require('fs');`) and then use the following line inside `folders.forEach()`: `fs.writeFile(`documents/${folder}${filename}`, content, 'utf8');`